# how to put two inline-block boxes underneath eachother

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes  each one is an inline-block  i want to put two inline-block boxes underneath each other , like the following image

[image]

here's the code i used

```css
.box1
 {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    height: 31%;
 }
  
  .box2 
  {
     background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 324px;
    float: right;
    height: 31%;
  }
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why are they inline if you don't want them to be inline?

Comment: Why are they floating if you don't want things next to them?

Comment: Considered just adding `<br>` into the HTML, between the two divs?

Answer (score 2):

In the second box clear your `float`. Just add `clear: both`.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  height: 31%;
}

.box2 {
  clear: both;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 324px;
  float: right;
  height: 31%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>

</body>
```

Comment: One observation. An `inline-block` which is floated becomes, in effect, a `block`.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap both your divs in a container and float that instead.

**example**

```css
.container {
  float: right;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 31%;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 324px;
  height: 31%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just add a "clear: both;" to your second div and otherwise leave your code as-is.

```css
.box1
 {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    height: 31%;
 }
  
  .box2 
  {
     background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 324px;
    float: right;
    height: 31%;
    clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>

</body>
```